# Angular exclude specific modules from being compiled with Ivy

Tags: angular, devextreme-angular, angular-ivy

I am using Angular 8 with ivy enabled. Everything works expect my devextreme components from devexpress. Currently this is not supported with Ivy.

Is there a way to compile everything but these modules with Ivy?